# Webpack - Turn Off Optimization Step During Build Process. Performance Speed Up

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a large build that is taking a 3-4 minutes during the optimization process.

I want to speed this up for development builds.

The output to the cmd prompt shows "73% optimize" and stays at 73% for 3-4 minutes.

How can I turn off the "optimize" process in the webpack build to speed up the development build?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [`angular-cli`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to compile your project?

If you do:

1. It's possible that you are being victim of a "known issue" of `angular-cli` of poor performance on Windows. It is said that [running angular-cli as administrator get things better](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/#known-issues) (ugly hack!)
2. Maybe it would be better to use `webpack` directly (without `angular-cli`) so you can configure `webpack` as you wish and tweak the build step. I would recommend you to take a look at AngularClass' [`angular2-webpack-starter`](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) which is a pre-configured angular 2 base project that uses `webpack` and many other useful things.